# Erro ao criar uma distribuição de um executável com banco sql usando o Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação desktop winforms com C# no Visual Studio com banco de dados Sql por meio do Entity Framework. A intenção é que seja uma base de dados local, o programa vai ser instalado em máquinas isoladas, que não têm acesso a nenhum servidor. Como sempre, na minha máquina funciona normal (risos), mas testando em outros computadores dá um erro de conexão com o Sql Server.

Estive pesquisando a respeito e vi que como acaba sendo inviável instalar o Sql Server em cada máquina, o melhor seria usar o Sql Server Compact. Porém, vi que ao contrário do Server Express que gera arquivos .mdf, o Compact trabalha com arquivos .sdf.

Neste a melhor saída seria reconfigurar o Entity Framework para gerar um banco Sql Compact ou existe alguma outra forma de trabalhar com o banco .mdf do Express em uma máquina que não tenha o Sql Server Express instalado?

Comment: tente esse [Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=54284) utilizando o `localdb` com `.mdf` mesmo

Comment: Oi, @Barbetta. Neste caso só seria possível acessar o bando se a máquina tiver o localDb instalado? Não existe alguma espécie de "runtime" do Sql Server que seja mais leve e de fácil instalação para o usuário?

Comment: Opa, quando passei pelo mesmo problema esse ai foi a única coisa que resolveu. Não sei se meu caso tem alguma peculiaridade, pois isso em primeiro momento comentei aqui. Esse ai é o service pack que traz os conectores para comunicar com o `localDb`.

Comment: Acabei optando pelo SQLite, por ser uma solução mais simples para o meu caso. Obrigado, @Barbetta

Comment: Vou te falar, essa semana tive que instalar a aplicação em uma máquina mais fraca e mais velha, me dei mal, tô indo pro mesmo caminho que o seu.

Comment: @Barbetta, Legal! Fico feliz em ter colaborado de alguma forma :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei encontrando uma solução melhor para a minha necessidade: SQLite.
O SQLite também tem suporte ao Entity Framework e acaba sendo bem mais simples de usar em uma aplicação stand-alone, não necessita de nenhuma instalação adicional na máquina do usuário e o pacote já gera as dlls necessárias. Para quem tiver interesse em um tutorial, neste [Link](http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2016/09/28/trabalhando-com-sqlite-no-c-e-vb-net/) há um passo a passo de como configurar e utilizar o SQLite inclusive com o Entity Framework.